# Blender Script (bpy) to Change colours of Voxel Faces

Tags: python, mesh, faces, blend-files, bmesh

I have a 3d voxel model of a human bust that looks very poor. Even after reducing the colour for each voxel face to a single colour, the resultant model does not look good.

I want the model to have a single color skin tone and hair colour. In my opinion, the best way to go about that would be to write a script that turns all brown, black, grey areas into stark black and turns all skin regions into whatever the first skin colour the script runs into while parsing the model.

Can anyone help out? I am a beginner with blender and have absolutely no idea where to start with writing such a bpy script

Image of voxelized model attached for reference:
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you can post a screenshot of your setup. Are all these different materials ?

Comment: @Gorgious I have added the voxelized model that I am trying to work on.